# Prolog Duplicate a word in list

Tags: list, prolog, duplicates

I have a Prolog code that duplicates whole list but what I want is duplicate only a single word(for example 'a'). For example;

```
dups([],[]).
dups([H|T],[H,H|Y]) :-
    dups(T,Y).
```

My code duplicates list `[a,b]` like => `[a, a ,b ,b]`.

But what i want is, duplicate list `[a, b]` like => `[a, a, b]`.

Comment: Only the *first* element? Or do you want to backtrack and thus generate a list for *every* element?

Comment: What I want is duplicate every 'a' characters in list. For Example; abaaccc =>aabaaaaccc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are describing lists you can opt to use DCGs. Consider the following rules:

```
x_dup(_X,[]) -->       % if the input list is empty
   [].                 % the output list is empty
x_dup(X,[X|Ys]) -->    % if X and the head of the list are equal
   [X,X],              % X is twice in the output list
   x_dup(X,Ys).        % the same holds for X and the tail
x_dup(X,[Y|Ys]) -->    % if X and the head of the input list
   {dif(X,Y)},         % are different
   [Y],                % the head is once in the output list
   x_dup(X,Ys).        % the same holds for X and the tail
```

If you are only interested in duplicating the head of the list, you can define the calling predicate like so:

```
dups([],[]).                    % <- only for empty list
dups([X|Xs],L) :-
   phrase(x_dup(X,[X|Xs]),L).
```

The first rule is only for dealing with the empty list. If you don't intend your predicate to cover that case just omit the first rule. Querying this with your example yields the desired result:

```
   ?- dups([a,b,a,a,c,c,c],L).
L = [a,a,b,a,a,a,a,c,c,c] ? ;
no
```

Alternatively, you can define the calling predicate such that you can duplicate an arbitrary element. In that case you need an additional argument to specify the element to be duplicated:

```
dups(X,L1,L2) :-
   phrase(x_dup(X,L1),L2).
```

Some example queries:

```
   ?- dups(a,[a,b,a,a,c,c,c],L).
L = [a,a,b,a,a,a,a,c,c,c] ? ;
no
   ?- dups(b,[a,b,a,a,c,c,c],L).
L = [a,b,b,a,a,c,c,c] ? ;
no
   ?- dups(c,[a,b,a,a,c,c,c],L).
L = [a,b,a,a,c,c,c,c,c,c] ? ;
no
   ?- dups(d,[a,b,a,a,c,c,c],L).
L = [a,b,a,a,c,c,c]
```

Comment: Thank you for your respond :)